# JideSplitPane proportions

Tags: java, swing

I have [JideSplitPane](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/JideSplitPane.html) component (horizontal split). Content in bottom panel changes and I need calculate new proportions for split pane (with new size of bottom panel).

How to do it?

I try:

```
double defBottomProportion = 0.4;
double bottomPanelHeight = manFrame.getHeight() * defBottomProportion;
double newBottmPanelHeight = bottomPanelHeight + additionalContentHeight;
double prop = newBottomPanelHeight / bottomPanelHeight;
defBottomProportion += prop;
splitPane.setPropertion(defBottomProportion);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a little bit on the "But it doesn't work"-bit? What exactly is not working? Do you get an exception, or is it not behaving as you expect? If it's a compile error, you should know you've misspelled setProportions().

Answer (score 1):

JideSplitPane expects an array of doubles, not a single value. The array must contain one less element than there are panes.

Try this (spelling corrected as well)

```
splitPane.setProportions(new double[] { defBottomProportion });
```